# django/nginx does not display media in production

Tags: nginx

When I make settings Debug = True,then all images are displayed. If Debug = False does not show.

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/

```
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/user/myprojectdir;
}

location = /media/ {
    root /home/user/myprojectdir;
}
```

Static and media folders are located in the root directory of the project
myprojectdir/static
myprojectdir/media

I use nginx+gunicorn,how do i get nginx to serve the media with Debug = False ?Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved,as I was told earlier there is an error in a typo - `location = /media/`- but it was necessary `location /media/` ,can anyone help:)